# Uniform Limit of Integrable Functions with Non-Compact Domain is Not Necessarily Integrable.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am trying to find an example of a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that: Each $f_n$ is integrable, $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly; the limit function $f$ is not integrable. Integrable means here normal Riemann integrable. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $f_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-1} \mathbb 1_{[k-1, k)}$ where $\mathbb 1_A$ is the indicator function of $A$.

Comment: @user251257 Can you please explain this example little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb 1_A$ denote the indicator function of the subset $A\subseteq \mathbb R$, that is $\mathbb 1_A(x)$ equals $1$ if $x\in A$ and $0$ otherwise.

Further for $n\in\mathbb N$ let 
$$ f_n = \sum_{k=1}^n k^{-1}(\mathbb 1_{[k-1,k)} - \mathbb 1_{[-k, -k+1)}) $$
and
$$ f = \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n. $$

Then, $f_n$ is Riemann integrable. But, for any $a\in \mathbb R$ we have
$$ \int_a^\infty f = \infty $$
and 
$$ \int_{-\infty}^a f = -\infty. $$
Hence, their sum is not defined and $f$ is not (improper) integrable.